# How to calculate new keyframe percentages in a css3 slider

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

i have a css slider that works fine with 4 images with a total animation duration of 30s. But now, i want to set the first image for 32sec, and the next 3, each image for 10sec, with a total of 62sec. I tried different combinations of keyframes percentages, but it`s impossible for me to deal with them.

Anyone knows a simple way to calculate them and to calculate the new animation duration?

Here`s the code:

```css
.slide > figure:nth-child(1)
{
 z-index: 4;
 opacity: 1;
 animation: slide1 30s;
 -webkit-animation: slide1 30s;
 -moz-animation: slide1 30s;
 -o-animation: slide1 30s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite; 
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes slide1
{
 0%{opacity:1;z-index:5;}
 24%{opacity:1;z-index:5;}
 26%{opacity:0;z-index:5;}
 27%{opacity:0;z-index:1;}
 94%{opacity:0;z-index:1;}
 95%{opacity:1;z-index:1;}
 96%{opacity:1;z-index:5;}
 100%{opacity:1;z-index:5;}
}

.slide > figure:nth-child(2)
{
 z-index: 3;
 opacity: 0;
 animation: slide2 30s;
 -webkit-animation: slide2 30s;
 -moz-animation: slide2 30s;
 -o-animation: slide2 30s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite; 
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes slide2
{
 0%{opacity:0;z-index:4;}
 23%{opacity:0;z-index:4;}
 24%{opacity:1;z-index:4;}
 25%{opacity:1;z-index:4;}
 26%{opacity:1;z-index:3;}
 49%{opacity:1;z-index:3;}
 51%{opacity:0;z-index:3;}
 52%{opacity:0;z-index:4;}
 100%{opacity:0;z-index:4;}
}

.slide > figure:nth-child(3)
{
 z-index: 2;
 opacity: 0;
 animation: slide3 30s;
 -webkit-animation: slide3 30s;
 -moz-animation: slide3 30s;
 -o-animation: slide3 30s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite; 
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes slide3
{
 0%{opacity:0;z-index:3;}
 48%{opacity:0;z-index:3;}
 49%{opacity:1;z-index:3;}
 50%{opacity:1;z-index:3;}
 51%{opacity:1;z-index:5;}
 74%{opacity:1;z-index:5;}
 76%{opacity:0;z-index:5;}
 77%{opacity:0;z-index:3;}
 100%{opacity:0;z-index:3;}
}

.slide > figure:nth-child(4)
{
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 0;
 animation: slide4 30s;
 -webkit-animation: slide4 30s;
 -moz-animation: slide4 30s;
 -o-animation: slide4 30s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite; 
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes slide4
{
 0%{opacity:0;z-index:2;}
 73%{opacity:0;z-index:2;}
 74%{opacity:1;z-index:2;}
 75%{opacity:1;z-index:2;}
 76%{opacity:1;z-index:5;}
 95%{opacity:1;z-index:5;}
 97%{opacity:0;z-index:5;}
 98%{opacity:0;z-index:2;}
 100%{opacity:0;z-index:2;}
}
```

Can anyone help me out? I really need a clear explanation to understand that :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way using animation-delay and 2 animations:

```
62s = 100%
32s = 32/62 = 51.6%
10s = 10/62 = 16%
```

```css
.slide > figure:nth-child(1) {
  animation: slide1 62s infinite;
}

.slide > figure:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0; z-index:1;
  animation: slide2 62s infinite;
}

.slide > figure:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0; z-index:1;
  animation: slide2 62s 10s infinite;
}

.slide > figure:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0; z-index:1;
  animation: slide2 62s 20s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide1 {
             52.6%, 100% {opacity:0; z-index:1;}
   0%, 51.6%             {opacity:1; z-index:5;}
}

@keyframes slide2 {
  0%, 52.6%,             70.6%, 100% {opacity:0; z-index:1;}
            53.6%, 69.6%             {opacity:1; z-index:5;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txt=Image-1">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txt=Image-2">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txt=Image-3">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txt=Image-4">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, timing works well..but images are so small when i tried them. Each image has a specific size set and each image has to be on top of the other like a slider, not under the last img like you post

Comment: That's another issue, if you need help on how to stack the images plz open another question.